# How to use ConnectionString in Client (Mobile) Code Securely

Tags: push-notification, connection-string, azure-notificationhub

We are using Notification Hub Connection String (static code as of now),  as an input to the NotificationHubSDK registration method.
The Connection string is composed of two parameters
Service Bus Endpoint URI 
Shared Access Key

Problem Statement -We are using above parameters in connection String which is exposing the URI+Shared access key inside our codebase using react-native-azurenotificationhub, hence if someone sees the codebase, will be able to access the notification hub through this information. And these can lead to the following threat
An unauthorized registration request can be made to the notification hub if someone can get access to the code.

Possible Solutions -

Microsoft recommended security is that to create the access policy just to listen, and recommend that do not use the full access key for client Side registration. (This has to configure d in notification hub, I have been talking about) 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-security

Official Documents Recommend using connection string with Listen access only in the codebase.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started

Handle the registration process from backend code (our own API),  which intern using Notification Hub Rest Api’s,  Device will call the Platform service (FCM or APS) and get the device token, and then pass the device token to the backend API,

```
   For achieving above, we need to write our own code, and we cannot utilize the Azure SDK.
```

Create a Web API, which will intern return the connection string from app settings JSON, based upon the environment. This API will be called from the device to get the connection string dynamically.

```
   We have discussed and finalized this solution as a workaround, and we are implementing the Web API part.  However, this also has below downside - 
   a. Need one extra API call in order to perform the device registration to notification hub
   b. At this point of time, our API is also not secure so anyone having access to the codebase can still access the final connection string. So the problem statement in the first place still not resolved.
```

Please provide us the best possible solution, where the mobile client can register to notification hub securely.

Please let me know what would be the best possible solution,

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following post on [Installation and Registration management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-registration-management).

Basically, you have the security concerns well understood. Notification Hubs only recommends distributing a "Listen only" access policy with client applications. However, I believe in your question, you're working under the assumption that one needs a full access policy to create a registration. This isn't the case, you should be able to do create installations and registrations using only the listen access policy.

Now that said, adding a layer of separation by handling registrations in the backend may still be a good idea. It will afford you flexibility in the case that you need to update a connection string. When the credentials are embedded in the application, you'll have to force your users to update their application if you ever need to change it. Imagine you have a security breach, and you need to change the credentials. If you have a backend, you just change some config server-side and keep moving. If you don't, your users will no longer receive notifications until the update. Clearly between the two, there's a better experience for your users.